# docker msys2: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: docker, msys2

Running Docker version 20.10.8, using Windows containers, I am attempting to mount a local directory for use within a MSYS2 container (base is `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2`, with MSYS2 installed at the usual location). I mount a local directory at `z:` when I run the container and launch MSYS bash, using the invocation:

```
docker run -v C:\path\to\dir:z: my:mingw-image C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -lc "ls /z/"
```

However, when I do so, I get the error:

```
ls: cannot access '/z/': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Some digging ([docker/for-win#109](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/109)) has led me to believe that this has something to do with a bad interaction between how Docker mounts `Z:` and how MSYS symlinks work, but I'm not sure if I'm just doing something obviously wrong (X/Y problem maybe?) or if this is just how it is.

I can seemingly work-around by first copying the contents of `Z:` to another location (like `C:\foo`) but this slows down the container run pretty significantly (especially during development).

Any workarounds/suggestions/thoughts? The overall goal is to be able to run an MSYS2-based build in CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution - `MSYS=nonativeinnerlinks`

From: https://github.com/msys2/msys2-runtime/issues/58

Seems to be something relatively new that was imported from cygwin to do with mapped network drives. Not entirely sure what